# How to use TestNG RetryAnalyzer to invoke new instance driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

How can I retry the test in TestNG using Selenium WebDriver if it failed?

I have used `retryAnalyser`. It works but not the way I want. I want to instantiate a new instance of the web driver: **"Start the test case from the beginning of the test"**.

Note that the instantiation of the web driver is in the `@BeforeClass`. This `@BeforeClass` is not in the same class as the `@Test` class. It is located in another class. The class that has the `@Test`, inherits the class that has `@BeforeClass` and all others annotations.

To be precise here a sample model:

```
public class A {
  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void setUp() {
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get(C.getURL());
    driver.switchTo().frame("top_frame");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }    

  @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void tearDown(ITestContext textContext) throws IOException {
    report.flush();
    driver.quit();          
  }    
}
```

// this is the test class

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = StartWebDriver.class)
public class TestCase extends StartWebDriver{
  @Test(testName = "Login to Application ")
  public void loginTestCase() {
    login.setUserName(C.getUSER_NAME());
    login.setPassword(C.getPASSWORD());
    login.clickLogin();
    deskTopMenu.newClaimClick();
    Assert.assertTrue(findPolicyPage.searchButton().isDisplayed()); 
  }
}
```

Note that I already write a retry analyzer class and override its method. I just didn't put in the sample code. Now, I have tried a lot of thing without success.

For example, I have moved the annotation to the class level instead of the test level. I also have created this in the in class `A` like:

```
@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext context) {
  for (ITestNGMethod method : context.getAllTestMethods()) {
    method.setRetryAnalyzer(new StartWebDriver());
  }
}
```

But all of these doesn't instantiate the driver. It's just starting over from where test step left. I need to start over before passing to next test. Note that each class has one test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the driver instantiation logic like:

```
public class A {
  @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
  public void setUp() {
    if (driver = null) {
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
      driver.get(C.getURL());
      driver.switchTo().frame("top_frame");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
  }

  @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
  public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getStatus() = FAILURE) {
       driver.quit();
       driver = null;
    } 
  }    

  @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void tearDown(ITestContext textContext) throws IOException {
    report.flush();
    if (driver != null) {
      driver.quit();       
    }   
  }    
}
```

Steps are:

1. Create a driver if it is not yet done
2. Run tests
3. If a test fails, remove the driver

Note: If the `@BeforeMethod` is not called in case of retry analyzer, you can keep your previous `@BeforeClass` method and create the new driver in the `@AfterMethod` method. Just make a driver create method to avoid code duplication  in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much Juherr, it was good logic ,but still doesn't work, It stil still try retesting  from the Method  test without inheriting The preconfig annotations

Comment: Thank you Juherr, I now working because its the only way in my case